# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PowerPacks' does not exist

Tags: vb.net, jenkins, powerpack

We have two Jenkins server, DEV and PRD. I am getting this error in PRD, but not in DEV. I see VB Power Pack is not installed in either server. Any other components may have this included in DEV?

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PowerPacks' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

We found the dlls in DEV, don't know how they got in there. We ended up to install VB PowerPack in both DEV and PRD.